# Making a table on a file with python

Tags: python, txt

I hope a similar question wasn't asked before. I am making a name and address table on a txt file using python, with the function f.write(str(dictionnary)), I can add elements to my file.

```
import sys
from prettytable import PrettyTable


def menu():
    
    print("0- Quit \n1 - Write \n2 - Search")
    choice = int(input("What is your choice?: "))
    if choice == 1:
        Write()
    if choice == 2:
        Search()
    else:
        sys.exit()
    
def Write():
    tablesp=PrettyTable(['Name',"Address"])
    while True:
        name = input("Name (0 to quit):")
        if name == "0":
            menu()
        addr = input("Address:")
        tablesp.add_row([name,addr])
        with open("file.txt","a") as f:
                f.write(str(tablesp))
                f.write("\n")
def Search():
    #I didn't write this part yet
    print("nothing here")

menu()
```

At the first try it gives this, which is okay

```
+--------+------------+
|  Name  |  Address   |
+--------+------------+
| myName | Washington |
+--------+------------+
```

But when when I add another person it creates a second table

```
+--------+------------+
|  Name  |  Address   |
+--------+------------+
| myName | Washington |
+--------+------------+
+-------------+---------+
|     Name    | Address |
+-------------+---------+
| myothername |    US   |
+-------------+---------+
```

I know the problem, it is due to rewriting another table. I am asking if there is a way to append the second name to the first table without creating another one. I am open to other methods too, if it can create a sort of json file, because I need to make a search function, where it has to find the address when I search the name.
Thank you.

Comment: You should provide a working code example, which this is not. What is probably the issue, is the fact that you create the table within the loop and don't just append to it. You could also split the code into functions for getting names, creating the table and writing the data.

Comment: Miles can you show the code you use for adding the second row? It seems to me you are creating a separate instance of PrettyTable

Comment: If I understood your question well, as it is a loop (while True), the program asks my a second time, so I write like that.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line: `with open("file.txt","a") as f:` to `with open("file.txt","w") as f:`. Notice I changed appending the file to (re)writing the file. Now the whole gets rewritten instead of adding a new table to an existing file.

Comment: This is actually something that I tried before, as I am printing tablesp, it automatically prints the headers no matter the position of the headers. So i think making with a table is not the most efficient way, is there another possibility

Comment: Post your whole code and I might be able to help you

Comment: I edited and posted my whole code. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for my super late response. I changed my answer.